# Non-trivial zero to an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots

In my free time, I was messing around with some maths, which eventually led me to the question of finding a non-trivial zero of the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^n}{1-x^n} $$

Does anybody maybe know a closed form (probably not)? Or does someone maybe know whether it has been studied before and has a name? If someone can help, that would be appreciated! (The zero I am looking for is around -0.41)

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+n+%3D+1+to+infinity+of+nx%5En%2F%281-x%5En%29) was not able to find a closed form for the sum.

Comment: For searching purposes: this is a [Lambert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series). The series considered by the OP is equivalent to $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sigma(k)x^k$$, where $$\sigma(k)=\sum_{d\mid k}d$$ is the [sum of divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite the sum as $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(nx^{mn}\right)$$

Switching the order of summation and evaluating, we get $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m}}{\left(x^{m}-1\right)^{2}}$$

Now [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bx%5Em%2F%28x%5Em+-+1%29%5E2%2C+%7Bm%2C+1%2C+Infinity%7D%5D) does not give a closed form for this, but it does give partial sums. Using that, the above sum is $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\psi_x^{(1)}(1)-\psi_x^{(1)}(n)}{\ln^2(x)}$$

Setting this equal to $0$ and simplifying, we get $$\psi_x^{(1)}(1) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \psi^{(1)}_x(n)$$

I think that $\psi_x(n)$ approaches a constant as $n$ approaches $\infty$, which makes the  RHS equal to $0$. Therefore, you want to solve $$\psi_x^{(1)}(1) = 0$$

Searching up the first few digits on the OEIS, I found [A143441](http://oeis.org/A143441). This gives a value of $$-0.41124847917795477344...$$ which when plugged into the original equation provides an error of $-1.14 \cdot 10^{-17}$.

Comment: You can use formula 2 for the $q$-polygamma function [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) and differentiate it.

Answer (score 2):

While I do not have a closed-form solution, I was able to solve it numerically using the Newton-Raphson method with the help of a Java program I coded. The answer is approximately

```
                                      x = -0.4112484443599058
```

If this value is plugged into the function provided, the $y$ value is within $\pm0.0000001$ of $0$. Sorry I could not provide a closed-form solution. The code for the Java program is attached if you would like to check it.

[Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCvu5.png)

I hope this helps!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

To have *approximations* of the solution of equation $$\psi_x^{(1)}(1) = 0$$ we could build around $x=0$ the $[1,n]$ Padé approximant of
$$\frac{\psi_x^{(1)}(1)}{x \, \log^2(x)}$$ this will generate for the *approximate* solution the sequence
$$-\frac{3}{5},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{2}{5},-\frac{25}{64},-\frac{2}{5},-\frac{16
   }{39},-\frac{39}{94},-\frac{94}{227},-\frac{454}{1103},-\frac{1103}{2688},-\frac
   {2688}{6547},$$ $$-\frac{6547}{15922},-\frac{7961}{19348},-\frac{96740}{235153},-\frac
   {470306}{1143585},-\frac{228717}{556214},-\frac{278107}{676299},-\frac{225433}{
   548170},$$ $$-\frac{93972}{228499},-\frac{228499}{555614},-\frac{9723245}{23643206},-\frac{23643206}{57491577},-\frac{57491577}{139798147},\cdots,$$
$$-\frac{2933110593712303331274025997834035269997622991978006995444}{7132210189750251
   897714249395557962621504069786938318973765},\cdots$$